# Access 2007 :onclick event is not working?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a button inside a from, i included the following code for the event onclick

```
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "INSERT INTO BusObjectiveUpdate (BusinessObjectDesc,BusinessReqID,BusObjectiveDate,PersonID) VALUES ('" & Me!BusinessObjectDesc & "'," & Me!BusinessReqID & "," & Me!BusObjectiveDate & "," & Me!PersonID & ");"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

Me.Requery
```

whenever i click on the button i check the table BusObjectiveUpdate and i found no data there ?! Any help ?!!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the database location to be a trusted location? In 2007 you need to do that in order for code to work.

Comment: I constructed the database in the same place where i am working on the forms, so i guess that there is no problem with the location

Comment: refer http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-remove-or-modify-a-trusted-location-for-your-files-HA010354311.aspx to set trusted location.

Comment: ,i added a trusted location just as  mentioned in the link, but i still have the same probelm ?!!!

Comment: oh oh , it works right now ! after i closed the database and reopened it, Thaank youu :) I really appreciate your help :):)

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention for reopening the database.